# How do i set a reflection for android.os.systemproperties?

Tags: android

So im trying to get this app to call android.os.SystemProperties from a reflection but its being kind of pain so if anyone could help it would be appreciated.

so this is the part of the code that is failing me:

```
        String str1 = SystemPropertiesProxy.get("ro.url.changelog");
        String str2 = SystemPropertiesProxy.get("ro.build.incremental");
        String str4 = String.format("?version=%s", str2);
        Object[] arrayOfObject1 = new Object[2];
        arrayOfObject1[0] = str1;
        arrayOfObject1[1] = str4;
        String str5 = String.format("%s%s", arrayOfObject1);
        ...
        myWebView.loadUrl(str5);
```

the code above gives me the error: "The method get(Context, String) in the Type SystemPropertiesProxy is not applicable for the arguments(String)" in the line "String str1 = SystemPropertiesProxy.get("ro.url.changelog")"
and this is the code for the reflection im trying to set to access android.os.SystemProperties:

```
package com.package.name;

import java.io.File;  
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import android.content.Context;
import dalvik.system.DexFile;


public class SystemPropertiesProxy
{

/**
 * This class cannot be instantiated
 */
private SystemPropertiesProxy(){

}

/**
 * Get the value for the given key.
 * @return an empty string if the key isn't found
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the key exceeds 32 characters
 */
public static String get(Context context, String key) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    String ret= "";

    try{

      ClassLoader cl = context.getClassLoader(); 
      @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
      Class SystemProperties = cl.loadClass("android.os.SystemProperties");

      //Parameters Types
      @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
      Class[] paramTypes= new Class[1];
      paramTypes[0]= String.class;

      Method get = SystemProperties.getMethod("get", paramTypes);

      //Parameters
      Object[] params= new Object[1];
      params[0]= new String(key);

      ret= (String) get.invoke(SystemProperties, params);

    }catch( IllegalArgumentException iAE ){
        throw iAE;
    }catch( Exception e ){
        ret= "";
        //TODO
    }

    return ret;

}

/**
 * Get the value for the given key.
 * @return if the key isn't found, return def if it isn't null, or an empty string otherwise
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the key exceeds 32 characters
 */
public static String get(Context context, String key, String def) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    String ret= def;

    try{

      ClassLoader cl = context.getClassLoader(); 
      @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
      Class SystemProperties = cl.loadClass("android.os.SystemProperties");

      //Parameters Types
      @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
      Class[] paramTypes= new Class[2];
      paramTypes[0]= String.class;
      paramTypes[1]= String.class;          

      Method get = SystemProperties.getMethod("get", paramTypes);

      //Parameters
      Object[] params= new Object[2];
      params[0]= new String(key);
      params[1]= new String(def);

      ret= (String) get.invoke(SystemProperties, params);

    }catch( IllegalArgumentException iAE ){
        throw iAE;
    }catch( Exception e ){
        ret= def;
        //TODO
    }

    return ret;

}

/**
 * Get the value for the given key, and return as an integer.
 * @param key the key to lookup
 * @param def a default value to return
 * @return the key parsed as an integer, or def if the key isn't found or
 *         cannot be parsed
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the key exceeds 32 characters
 */
public static Integer getInt(Context context, String key, int def) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    Integer ret= def;

    try{

      ClassLoader cl = context.getClassLoader(); 
      @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
      Class SystemProperties = cl.loadClass("android.os.SystemProperties");

      //Parameters Types
      @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
      Class[] paramTypes= new Class[2];
      paramTypes[0]= String.class;
      paramTypes[1]= int.class;  

      Method getInt = SystemProperties.getMethod("getInt", paramTypes);

      //Parameters
      Object[] params= new Object[2];
      params[0]= new String(key);
      params[1]= new Integer(def);

      ret= (Integer) getInt.invoke(SystemProperties, params);

    }catch( IllegalArgumentException iAE ){
        throw iAE;
    }catch( Exception e ){
        ret= def;
        //TODO
    }

    return ret;

}

/**
 * Get the value for the given key, and return as a long.
 * @param key the key to lookup
 * @param def a default value to return
 * @return the key parsed as a long, or def if the key isn't found or
 *         cannot be parsed
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the key exceeds 32 characters
 */
public static Long getLong(Context context, String key, long def) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    Long ret= def;

    try{

      ClassLoader cl = context.getClassLoader();
      @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
      Class SystemProperties= cl.loadClass("android.os.SystemProperties");

      //Parameters Types
      @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
      Class[] paramTypes= new Class[2];
      paramTypes[0]= String.class;
      paramTypes[1]= long.class;  

      Method getLong = SystemProperties.getMethod("getLong", paramTypes);

      //Parameters
      Object[] params= new Object[2];
      params[0]= new String(key);
      params[1]= new Long(def);

      ret= (Long) getLong.invoke(SystemProperties, params);

    }catch( IllegalArgumentException iAE ){
        throw iAE;
    }catch( Exception e ){
        ret= def;
        //TODO
    }

    return ret;

}

/**
 * Get the value for the given key, returned as a boolean.
 * Values 'n', 'no', '0', 'false' or 'off' are considered false.
 * Values 'y', 'yes', '1', 'true' or 'on' are considered true.
 * (case insensitive).
 * If the key does not exist, or has any other value, then the default
 * result is returned.
 * @param key the key to lookup
 * @param def a default value to return
 * @return the key parsed as a boolean, or def if the key isn't found or is
 *         not able to be parsed as a boolean.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the key exceeds 32 characters
 */
public static Boolean getBoolean(Context context, String key, boolean def) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    Boolean ret= def;

    try{

      ClassLoader cl = context.getClassLoader(); 
      @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
      Class SystemProperties = cl.loadClass("android.os.SystemProperties");

      //Parameters Types
      @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
      Class[] paramTypes= new Class[2];
      paramTypes[0]= String.class;
      paramTypes[1]= boolean.class;  

      Method getBoolean = SystemProperties.getMethod("getBoolean", paramTypes);

      //Parameters         
      Object[] params= new Object[2];
      params[0]= new String(key);
      params[1]= new Boolean(def);

      ret= (Boolean) getBoolean.invoke(SystemProperties, params);

    }catch( IllegalArgumentException iAE ){
        throw iAE;
    }catch( Exception e ){
        ret= def;
        //TODO
    }

    return ret;

}

/**
 * Set the value for the given key.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the key exceeds 32 characters
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the value exceeds 92 characters
 */
public static void set(Context context, String key, String val) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    try{

      @SuppressWarnings("unused")
      DexFile df = new DexFile(new File("/system/app/Settings.apk"));
      @SuppressWarnings("unused")
      ClassLoader cl = context.getClassLoader(); 
      @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
      Class SystemProperties = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");

      //Parameters Types
      @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
      Class[] paramTypes= new Class[2];
      paramTypes[0]= String.class;
      paramTypes[1]= String.class;  

      Method set = SystemProperties.getMethod("set", paramTypes);

      //Parameters         
      Object[] params= new Object[2];
      params[0]= new String(key);
      params[1]= new String(val);

      set.invoke(SystemProperties, params);

    }
    catch( IllegalArgumentException iAE ){
        throw iAE;
    }
    catch( Exception e ){
        //TODO
    }

}
}
```

Again any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

u didn't write tat this is compiler error

there is no method

```
public static String get(String key){}
```

in SystemPropertiesProxy. use

```
public static String get(Context context, String key):


SystemPropertiesProxy.get(context, "ro.url.changelog");
```

anyway ... using private API is not a good idea

Comment: I'd extend "using private API is not a good idea" to "using a private API is stupid".

Comment: i need to, if you have any other idea on how i can call that from build.prop ill be glad to hear. im starting with android dev and dont have experience enough.

Comment: u mean android.os.Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL

Comment: it doesnt matter i need it to set the string from the buil.prop thats all.